# calling java method from hbase shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a requirement where I need to create a custom Hbase Shell command and call java method.

I was able to create a custom hbase command by creating a ruby script and add that script in Shell.rb file. Now I want to know how to call the custom java method from the ruby script which was defined under shell/commands dir.